# Can buffers regulate the pH, or do they just smooth out pH bumps?

Tags: ph

Hydrogen carbonate can react with hydrogen ions to create carbonic acid which degrades into water and carbon dioxide that can be exhaled or excreted otherwise. That lowers the pH, yes. However, in order to create new hydrogen carbonate ions, the reverse pathway takes place, and pH is raised. So, this will help smooth out the bumps in the pH, but can it somehow regulate it long-term?

Comment: This question is better suited for chemistry.